# Calculate conditional format color(i.e Red , Green) in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I just want to Count conditionally format Greater Than and Less Than (Red and Greens) , Please any simple formula.

Answer (score 0):

You can use count if with a condition as long as that condition is surrounded by apostrophes's

for example to count cells in column A that are greater than 10:

```
countif(A:A,">10")
```

You can match this condition to that of the conditional format to count the number of red or greens depending on condition.